# Run different projects on a single server

Tags: java, ide, jboss, intellij-idea, jboss-4.2.x

I'd like to run different projects on a single JBoss AS in IntelliJ IDEA (different *projects*, not different *modules*). All the projects should support hot deployment.

I know how to do that in Eclipse, but I've got no idea of how to do it in IntelliJ IDEA. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I work around this by adding Maven Projects to my window (Maven Projects tab -> (+) Add Maven Project). My projects don't share anything, they have their own modules and their own artifacts. While editing configuration for my jboss, clicking Deployment -> Add, all the web modules from all my projects show up and I can add them one by one. Hopefully you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA module is the same as Eclipse project, [see the FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html). Having multiple modules in one IDEA project allows you to deploy several modules at the same time to the same server.

Comment: These projects don't have anything in common (like for example a Maven parent project). And according to the FAQ _There's no exact equivalent to Eclipse's workspace that contains all your work, but you can open multiple projects in multiple frames at the same time._

Comment: Yes, that is true. You may try remote JBoss configuration to deploy different projects to a single server.